# (babel plugin) Error: .sourceMap must be a boolean, "inline", "both", or undefined

Tags: babeljs, nuxt.js, source-maps, rollup

When attempting to package a nuxt component, I get the above error. I am running nuxt 2.4.5, @babel/core 7.0.0 and rollup 1.4.0.

Does anyone have any thoughts?
Thanks in advance..

npm run script:

```
"build:es": "rollup --config build/rollup.config.js --format es --file dist/cxl-nuxt-map.esm.js"
```

Command :

nr build:es

```
cxl-nuxt-map@1.0.0 build:es /Users/userinfo/Projects/cxl-nuxt-map rollup --config build/rollup.config.js --format es --file dist/cxl-nuxt-map.esm.js
```

index.js → dist/cxl-nuxt-map.esm.js...

Stack Trace:

```
[!] (babel plugin) Error: .sourceMap must be a boolean, "inline", "both", or undefined
index.js
Error: .sourceMap must be a boolean, "inline", "both", or undefined
    at assertSourceMaps (/Users/dan.mahoney/Projects/cxl-nuxt-map/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/option-assertions.js:65:11)
    at Object.keys.forEach.key (/Users/dan.mahoney/Projects/cxl-nuxt-map/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/options.js:107:5)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at validateNested (/Users/dan.mahoney/Projects/cxl-nuxt-map/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/options.js:83:21)
    at validate (/Users/dan.mahoney/Projects/cxl-nuxt-map/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/options.js:74:10)
    at file (/Users/dan.mahoney/Projects/cxl-nuxt-map/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:174:34)
    at cachedFunction (/Users/dan.mahoney/Projects/cxl-nuxt-map/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:33:19)
    at buildRootChain (/Users/dan.mahoney/Projects/cxl-nuxt-map/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:120:36)
    at loadPrivatePartialConfig (/Users/dan.mahoney/Projects/cxl-nuxt-map/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:85:55)
    at Object.loadPartialConfig (/Users/dan.mahoney/Projects/cxl-nuxt-map/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:110:18)
    at Object.babel.loadPartialConfig (/Users/dan.mahoney/Projects/cxl-nuxt-map/node_modules/rollup-plugin-babel/src/index.js:80:20)
    at /Users/dan.mahoney/Projects/cxl-nuxt-map/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:17051:25
    at process.runNextTicks [as _tickCallback] (internal/process/next_tick.js:47:5)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:804:11)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cxl-nuxt-map@1.0.0 build:es: `rollup --config build/rollup.config.js --format es --file dist/cxl-nuxt-map.esm.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cxl-nuxt-map@1.0.0 build:es script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/dan.mahoney/.npm/_logs/2019-03-01T20_10_17_889Z-debug.log
```

Rollup.config.js:

```
/* rollup.config.js */
import vue from 'rollup-plugin-vue';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace';
import { plugin as analyze } from 'rollup-plugin-analyzer';

export default {
  input: 'index.js',
  output: {
    name: 'CxlNuxtMap',
    exports: 'named',
  },
  plugins: [
    postcss({
      extensions: ['.css'],
      runtimeHelpers: true,
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    }),
    vue(),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    }),
    replace({
      'process.env.INCLUDE_DEPS': JSON.stringify('false'),
    }),
    replace({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
    }),
    commonjs({
      namedExports: {},
    }),

    analyze({ stdout: true }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: Please include the stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Found in the problem in my .babelrc file. The offending line was:

`"sourceMap": "true",`

should be:

`"sourceMaps": true,`